# Icon cannot align to div center when use bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is [my code](https://gist.github.com/roroco/f885d74cc7d207942df64f27c8eb1f5c)

I use following code to align icon to div center:

```
<div class="webview-back icon"
     style="width: 34px; height: 34px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; background-color: lightgray;"><i
    class="fa fa-arrow-left" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</div>
```

like following:
[image]

But when I add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">`, icon become align to top

[image]

I don't wanna use bootstrap .btn, is there any way to align icon to div center even I use bootstrap.css?

Comment: Add `line-height: 34px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you use `style=""` I would prefer to create CSS classes, but in case you need to do it that way then is ok.

You can play with `line-height`, for example: `line-height: 34px`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="webview-back icon"
style="line-height: 34px; width: 34px; height: 34px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; background-color: lightgray;"><i
    class="fa fa-arrow-left" style="vertical-align: middle;"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: since `<div>` code is used in Vue.component, style don't need additional css file

Comment: add line-height fix my question

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a beautiful thing

I've split up you HTML and CSS just so it's easier to read.

I've added these 3 lines

```
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

- Line 1 set the display mode to inline (externally) and flex
  (internally)
- Line 2 vertically aligns the contents centrally
- Line 3 horizontally aligns the contents centrally

```css
.webview-back.icon {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="webview-back icon">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
</div>
```

Hope you find this helpful